# Can the product of a simple and a non-simple indecomposable representation be semisimple?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Consider two (possibly infinite-dimensional) representations $\rho$, $\pi$ of a semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, with $\rho$ irreducible and $\pi$ indecomposable but *not irreducible* (i.e., not simple). Are there any circumstances under which the product representation $\rho\otimes\pi$ can be semisimple (isomorphic to a direct sum of irreducible representations)?

In other words: is the product of a simple and a non-semisimple representation *always* non-semisimple?

## Motivation

I'm working in particular with $\mathfrak{spin}(3,1)$. The situation is the following: I have a class of irreducible finite-dimensional representations (the $\rho$ above) that I know how to couple with generic irreducible representations $\sigma$ (that is, I know under which conditions the resulting representation is semisimple or not).
I need to find out if the product $\rho_1\otimes\rho_2\otimes\sigma$ is semisimple: if $\rho_2\otimes\sigma$ is, then I can consider the product with $\rho_1$ for each one of the irreducibles in the decomposition to obtain the answer; if, however, $\rho_2\otimes\sigma$ is indecomposable but not irreducible, can I be sure that $\rho_1\otimes\rho_2\otimes\sigma$ is not semisimple as well?
I'm expecting the resulting representation to be *not* semisimple, but I need an answer to my question to be able to prove it.

## Update #1

As Will Sawin pointed out, if $\rho$ is finite dimensional and $\rho\otimes\pi$ happens to be semisimple, then it must necessarily be $\rho^*\otimes\rho\otimes\pi$ non-semisimple, since $\rho^*\otimes\rho$ is semisimple and contains the trivial representation in its decomposition. Unfortunately this doesn't contradict anything, as it is possible for the product of two semisimple representations to be non-semisimple.

Comment: I'm not sure what the answer is, but does it have consequences (either way)?    There tend to be lots of exotic infinite dimensional representations of such Lie algebras, so it's hard to predict what is possible.   There don't seem to be examples in the BGG category of such semisimple tensor products with $\rho$ finite dimensional and $\pi$ of course not; but this category of modules is very restrictive.    If I had to guess, I'd expect to find no examples of the type you describe.

Comment: @JimHumphreys: I added some motivation for my question, to explain the consequences. I'm expecting not to find any example as well, but I need to be sure.

Comment: If $\rho$ is finite-dimensional, the reverse has to happen also - $(\rho \otimes \pi)$ is semsimple but $\rho^\vee \otimes (\rho \otimes \pi)$ is not.

Comment: @WillSawin: Is $\rho^\vee$ the dual representation in your notation? Can you elaborate on why this  has to happen?

Comment: Yes, that's the dual. Because $\rho$ is finite dimensional, $1$ is a summand of $\rho^\vee \otimes \rho$, so $\pi$ is a summand of $\rho^\vee \otimes \rho \otimes \pi$.

Comment: As Jim Humphreys suggests, it would be helpful to know what kind of "generic irreducible representations" $\sigma$ you are considering? Do they have any special properties? The fact that you have information about the semi-simplicity of $\rho\otimes\sigma$ leads me to think there is more relevant information available.

Comment: @DavidHill: I'm considering the infinite dimensional representations given by Harish-Chandra in his paper ["Infinite Irreducible Representations of the Lorentz Group"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1947.0047).